# Interval extensionality?

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

For example, in the proof of lemma 6.4.1 in the HoTT book, a function inductively defined over a function is simply applied on paths `loop` and `refl`, and then a path between `loop` and `refl` is used (presumably by congruence via `f`) to construct a path between `f loop` and `f refl`:

> Suppose that `loop = refl base`. [...] with `x : A`
>   and `p : x = x`, there is a function `f : S1 → A` defined by `f(base) :≡ x` and `f(loop) := p`, we have
>
> ```
> p = f(loop) = f(refl base) = refl x.
> ```

But in a cubical setting, things are not so clear-cut. `f(loop)` is not well-typed, only `f(loop i)` is, for some `i : I`. But then that above proof becomes

```
p = <i> f (loop i) = <i> f (refl base i) = refl x
```

but doesn't that need some kind of "interval extensionality" in the middle   step? What exactly is the justification of the middle step in cubical type theory? I can see how to prove `∀ i → f (loop i) = f (refl base i)`, but how does one "lift" that to `<i> f (loop i) = <i> f (refl base i)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally I was going to give an assurance that something like your extensionality principle must hold, but I decided to puzzle out enough cubical Agda to actually demonstrate the proof.

However, I should say that your `all : ∀ i → f (loop i) = f (refl base i)` is actually a digression. This is equivalent to a square with *arbitrary* sides, which looks like this:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
x @>all(0)>> x \\
@VpVV \Rightarrow @VVreflV \\
x @>>all(1)> x
\end{CD}
$$

but something with type `p ≡ refl` is actually more uniform than that, because if `e` has that type, then `e i : x ≡ x` *regardless of* `i`, which is more uniform than the above square (where `e i : all i0 i ≡ all i1 i`), and is equivalent to a square of the form:

$$
\begin{CD}
x @>refl>> x \\
@VpVV \Rightarrow @VVreflV \\
x @>>refl> x
\end{CD}
$$

*But*, if we have `loop ≡ refl`, we already have this sort of square, and applying `f` point-wise produces a new square of this type. So, the following code is accepted:

```
module Path
    (S1 Z : Set)
    (base : S1)
    (loop : base ≡ base)
    (f : S1 → Z)
    (x : Z)

    (sq : loop ≡ refl)
  where
  rfl : base ≡ base
  rfl = refl

  z : Z
  z = f base

  p : z ≡ z
  p i = f (loop i)

  zrfl : z ≡ z
  zrfl = refl

  hsq : p ≡ zrfl
  hsq j i = f (sq j i)
```

So, the bit in the HoTT book is just a consequence of the composition of 'functions'.

The more arbitrary square can be expressed using the `PathP` type, which is also written `_[_≡_]` in cubical Agda, and the proof of equivalence to the ∀ type is:

```
module Square
    (A : Set)
    (x y : A)
    (e₁ e₂ : x ≡ y)
    (lines : ∀ i → e₁ i ≡ e₂ i)
  where
  f₀ : x ≡ x
  f₀ = lines i0

  f₁ : y ≡ y
  f₁ = lines i1

  square : (λ i → e₁ i ≡ e₂ i) [ f₀ ≡ f₁ ]
  square i j = lines i j
```

If you want to fool around with cubical Agda yourself to try this out interactively, I've been using a recent Agda from the development branch with `{-# OPTIONS --cubical #-}`, along with [this library](https://github.com/Saizan/cubical-demo).